# Simplify if-clauses when checking for range and setting default value

Tags: c#, if-statement, sbyte

I have a function that converts a `double` value into the `sbyte` and returns its hex representation:

```
string convertToSByte(double num, double factor)
{

    double _Value = num * factor;

    if (_Value > 127)
    {
        _Value = 127;
    }
    else if (_Value < -127)
    {
        _Value = -127;
    }

    return Convert.ToSByte(_Value).ToString("X2");
}
```

The calculated `_Value` is supposed to be within the range of `[-127 ; 127]` if not then these values have to be set as default.

Question: How can these two if conditions and the setting of the default values be simplified?

EDIT:

I tried using the conditional operator `?` but actually it is not much simpler (even a little harder to read) and also not really less code

ps. This question serves more of an educational purpose. To find a different way to check for ranges of a variable

Comment: Why do you need to simplify? Your code is quite simple, straightforward and easy to understand.

Comment: @HimBromBeere I guess for the sake of learn to think in different ways. It has more an educational effect. In production code I would always favor this way of writing that I posted

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `Min`/`Max`

```
string convertToSByte(double num, double factor)
{
    var value = Math.Min(127, Math.Max(-127.0, num * factor));
    return Convert.ToSByte(value).ToString("X2");
}
```

Comment: splendid! Thank you very much. I wait a little for other answers to arrive, but your post is the first candidate for accepting as correct answer.